# [LLVM-9 clang-9 OSX]: std::filesystem::path unrecognized

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++, libc++, std-filesystem

Hello after upgrading on OSX Mojave to the version LLVM-9 using `brew upgrade llvm`

I got the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/roman/CLionProjects/Milerius/antara-gaming-sfml-template/cmake-build-debug/_deps/antara-gaming-sdk-src/modules/core/antara/gaming/core/real.path.cpp:17:
/Users/roman/CLionProjects/Milerius/antara-gaming-sfml-template/cmake-build-debug/_deps/antara-gaming-sdk-src/modules/core/antara/gaming/core/real.path.hpp:23:22: fatal error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path binary_real_path() noexcept;
                     ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/filesystem:738:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
```

my code:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

namespace antara::gaming::core
{
    std::filesystem::path binary_real_path() noexcept;
    std::filesystem::path assets_real_path() noexcept;
}
```

Is this normal ?

Comment: Do you set `-std=c++17` while compiling with clang?

Comment: Yes of course and also `-std=c++17 -lc++fs`

Comment: Try to add `-stdlib=libc++` and `-lc++experimental`

Comment: `'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15` suggests it's seeing the Xcode-default version of `<filesystem>` instead of the llvm-9 homebrew version...

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/filesystem:` this line suggest that he is looking for the llvm brew include directory no ?

Comment: @trojanfo it's not using the xcode version of libc++ it is using the llvm9 libc++, read the source code and you will see the attributes for it.

Answer (score 1):

of one the solution is to using: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.15` compiler flags

In CMake:

```
add_library(antara_cross_filesystem INTERFACE)
add_library(antara::cross_filesystem ALIAS antara_cross_filesystem)

target_link_libraries(antara_cross_filesystem INTERFACE
        $<$<AND:$<PLATFORM_ID:Linux>,$<VERSION_LESS:$<CXX_COMPILER_VERSION>,9.0>>:stdc++fs>
        $<$<AND:$<PLATFORM_ID:Darwin>,$<VERSION_LESS:$<CXX_COMPILER_VERSION>,9.0>>:c++fs>)
target_compile_options(antara_cross_filesystem INTERFACE
        $<$<AND:$<PLATFORM_ID:Darwin>,$<VERSION_GREATER:$<CXX_COMPILER_VERSION>,8.0>>:-mmacosx-version-min=10.15>)
```