# Does llvm 9 support std::filesystem on versions of the mac prior to 10.15?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, llvm, std-filesystem

I have an old Mac (circa 2009) running El Capitan version 10.11.6.  Apple doesn't allow further updates of its OS on my machine, but through Macports it serves as a fine development environment for non-Apple-specific software.

I'm compiling with g++ 9.2, which supports std::filesystem out of the box, and with clang 8.0, which doesn't.  (Using each compiler's native standard library, in each case.)  And I'm compiling with --std=c++2a.

I've noticed the llvm 9 is supposed to support std::filesystem out of the box (https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-filesystem), so I downloaded clang/llvm 9 through Macports.  Unfortunately, I'm hitting a snag.

Minimal code to reproduce error is a simplification of the example from cppreference.com (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path)

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int
main()
{
   fs::path p1 = "/usr/lib/sendmail.cf";

   std::cout << "p1 = " << p1 << '\n';
}
```

And here's the CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.5)
project(bug LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable (bug main.cpp)
target_compile_options(bug PRIVATE "-std=c++2a")
```

And here's the compiler's complaints:

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /opt/local/bin/cmake --build ~/temp/build/debug/clang --config debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] [1/2  50% :: 1.598] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bug.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/bug.dir/main.cpp.o 
[build] /opt/local/bin/clang++    -g   -std=c++2a -MD -MT CMakeFiles/bug.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/bug.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/bug.dir/main.cpp.o -c ../../../main.cpp
[build] ../../../main.cpp:9:8: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
[build]    fs::path p1 = "/usr/lib/sendmail.cf";
[build]        ^
[build] /opt/local/libexec/llvm-9.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/filesystem:738:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
[build] class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
...
```

Working backward, I find this bit of code in /opt/local/libexec/llvm-9.0/include/c++/v1/__config:

```
#  define _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FILESYSTEM                                      \
     __attribute__((availability(macosx,strict,introduced=10.15)))             \
     __attribute__((availability(ios,strict,introduced=13.0)))                 \
     __attribute__((availability(tvos,strict,introduced=13.0)))                \
     __attribute__((availability(watchos,strict,introduced=6.0)))
```

As far as I can determine, this #define is the ultimate cause of the above error message.

So, my questions are:

- Is this a bug with LLVM?  After all, GCC doesn't introduce a dependency between std::filesystem and the OS version.
- Is this a bug with Macports?  Maybe they didn't use the correct flags when building?
- If I were to build LLVM and Clang natively, can I work around this issue?
- Is it an issue at all?  Maybe the good folks at LLVM know something that the good folks at GCC don't.

NOTE: There's a similar question involving clang/llvm downloaded through Homebrew.  Unfortunately, the commentary was not helpful.  [[LLVM-9 clang-9 OSX]: std::filesystem::path unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131130/llvm-9-clang-9-osx-stdfilesystempath-unrecognized)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking through LLVM and encountered the following [lines](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/b38c08ac02460b5555b9d6c8468db4d58eb4ef9c/libcxx/include/__config#L1310-L1318):

```cpp
// Decide whether to use availability macros.
#if !defined(_LIBCPP_BUILDING_LIBRARY) &&                                      \
    !defined(_LIBCPP_DISABLE_AVAILABILITY) &&                                  \
    __has_feature(attribute_availability_with_strict) &&                       \
    __has_feature(attribute_availability_in_templates)
#  ifdef __APPLE__
#    define _LIBCPP_USE_AVAILABILITY_APPLE
#  endif
#endif
```

So I passed `-D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_AVAILABILITY` to the compiler and it worked! I doubt that it's a valid solution, but it may help someone. Another option could be sticking to https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem which is basically `std::filesystem`, but outside of the standard library.

Answering some of your questions:

> Is this a bug with LLVM? After all, GCC doesn't introduce a dependency between std::filesystem and the OS version.

Well, it's not a bug, but yes, it's a feature of LLVM and it seems that it's made especially for Apple.

> Is this a bug with Macports? Maybe they didn't use the correct flags when building?

No, it's not a bug of Macports or Homebrew.

> If I were to build LLVM and Clang natively, can I work around this issue?

As you could see this availability feature is in the sources, so it seems that it doesn't matter if you build it from sources or using a package manager.

> Is it an issue at all? Maybe the good folks at LLVM know something that the good folks at GCC don't.

Unfortunately, I can't state anything here, but it should've been done for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which reinforces what I've found.  I ended up implementing std::filesystem (POSIX only), and only a few weeks ago came across gulrak's work.  I'm planning to keep my implementation, and maybe optimize it over time.